# Matplotlib slider to move vertical axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a slider to move a vertical axis. I'm able to create a vertical axis with:

```
plt.axvline(0.5, color = 'green')
```

My code is based on [matplotlip's `slider_demo.py` example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html).

In that code, to update the graph, they call:

```
l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
```

where

```
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2, color='red')
```

How can I change this to update a vertical axis linked to a slider? (Which arguments should I use to give to `set_data` to create a `vertical_axis` or another function to use to update that axis?)

Edit:

To be more specific, doing :

```
plt.axvline(slider.val, color = 'green')
```

in the update function of the slider
creates a new vertical axis when moving the slider but doesn't remove the previously existing one.
If I do

```
v = plt.axvline(0.5, color = 'green')
```

and in the update function

```
v.remove()
v = plt.axvline(slider.val, color = 'green')
```

it doesn't work, the axes stays at the same place. If i do in the update function :

```
v.remove()
plt.axvline(slider.val, color = 'green')
```

It works the first time I move my slider, but not after that.

Comment: For a vertical line you probably want to update the x value, `set_xdata([slider.val,slider.val])`

Comment: Doing v.set_xdata(slider.val) does the trick. Thank you very much!!!